# SQL IN and NOT IN alternative?

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a way to optimize my following SQL query which is taking a long time to run:

```
(s.StaffID in (Select sch.StaffID From Schedule sch
                where sch.AccountID=@AccountID
                  and sch.Date Between DATEADD(day, -90, @Today) and @Today
                  and sch.Status<>2))
AND
(s.StaffID Not in (Select sch.StaffID From Schedule sch
                    where sch.AccountID=@AccountID
                      and sch.Date Between DATEADD(day, -90, @Today) and @Today
                      and sch.Status=2))
```

Can I replace it with another simple query which does less work?

Comment: could you give details what you tried to attain here `sch.Status<>2` and 'NOT sch.Status=2' sounds same

Comment: I am trying to find staffid's that are in schedule table with status<>2, but if there is at least one schedule that is having staff with status=2, that staff should not be taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to combine the two expressions:

```
s.staffid in
(
  select staffid 
  from schedule
  where accountid = @accountid
    and date between dateadd(day, -90, @today) and @today 
  group by staffid  
  having count(case when status <> 2 then 1 end) > 0
     and count(case when status = 2 then 1 end) = 0
)
```

Comment: I added the following line to it:                                                                 AND (s.StaffID in (select distinct(staffid) from schedule where accountid=@AccountID and date between dateadd(day, -90, @today) and @today)) to also get those staff who are having no schedules in those 90 days. But it is not filtering? What i am doing here?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to add this. We already consider staff IDs within the last 90 days only. I don't understand what you want to achieve. Anyway, you can move conditions to and from `WHERE` and `CASE`. Right now we take all schedules of the past 90 days and make sure they have a status <> 2 and no status = 2. (Well the first condition will be superfluous, if status cannot be null, obviously.) You can remove the date range condition from `WHERE` and add date range conditions the the `CASE` clauses where needed, if you want different results.

Comment: The thing i am trying to find are those staffid's who dont have any schedules with status=2 in past 90 days. Even if there is at least one schedule with status=2, it should not get filtered. this was accomplished by doing above query. But now i came up with a situation what if staff does not have a schedule in past 90 days. Then those staffid's should come under status<>2 category so that i can mark them as inactive. I am trying this:

Comment: GROUP BY StaffID HAVING count(case when status <> 2 and date between dateadd(day,-90,@today) and @today then 1 end)>0 and count(case when status = 2 then 1 end) = 0 ) which didn't perform what i wanted

Comment: If you only want to exclude all staff with status 2 in the last 90 days, isn't this simply: `s.staff_id not in (select staffid from schedule where  date between dateadd(day, -90, @today) and @today and status = 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd move this logic into sub-query like this:

```
select s.StaffID 
from StaffID as s inner join (
    Select StaffID
    From Schedule
    where
        AccountID=@AccountID and
        Date Between DATEADD(day, -90, @Today) and @Today and
    group by StaffID
    having max(case when Status=2 then 2 else 1 end) = 1
) as t
on (s.StaffID = t.StaffID)
```

So, condition in `having` will filter out members who had status==2 in past 90 days